# Building Python h5py on Lion; gcc fail

Tags: osx-lion, python, gcc

I am trying to build `h5py` on OS X Lion; I'm using Python 2.7.2 installed from Scipy Superpack. Using either `pip` and `setup.py` approach, I get the same error:

```
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /blah/blah
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

This is my gcc version which I had to link with `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2`

```
$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1
```

Is it because of 32/64-bit compatibility? Is there a way around this?

Comment: What is `/blah/blah`?

Comment: Some temporary directory that seems to change every time. like `/var/` and then what appears to be a random sequence of characters/numbers.

Comment: Did you solve this out? My guess is that Scipy Superpack (whatever it is) is not compiled to be compatible with GCC shipped with Lion.

Comment: I'm using gcc from XCode or Macports, but I thought it was the same that was used to build Scipy Superpack. In the end, I just installed EPD.